# Algorithm for identifying route in urban subways

Tags: algorithm, graph-databases, linear-programming

I have some 26 subway stations and I have built a route id for each possible journey including which line and transfer point.

As a device travels through the subway network I collect bluetooth probes as they are seen at the different locations.  The probes are not always picked up at every station.

What I am trying to understand is the best approach to taking the probe data and classifying which route the a device traveled.  The ultimate goal is to understand what percentage of devices choose different routes that have the same start and end station and what affect the time of day has.

Ideally this is something I would like to address without the aid of machine learning.

Here is an illustration of the problem:[image: subway map]

Comment: When you collect bluetooth probe,then you might be getting info about that device also right, now once all the devices reach their destination, can't you plot a route map, like now you will have the info like, as station 1 - these two devices probes were caught and something like that for all the devices

Comment: I did not completely understand your question. What is a route id? What is a traveling device? How does the probe data look like? If I am guessing I would say  [HMMs](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_Model) could help you.

Comment: You're probably going to end with several *possible* routes that the device *might* have taken and are compatible with the probes you detected *and the times they were detected*. You would then add the fractional values. At each stop you would need to recurse the possible routes from that stop, and prune those that aren't compatible with the detection times. So you might conclude that after probe #2, the device actually turned *right* and made one stop, then went back and at last was detected at #3 (or it dismounted/remounted the subway at #3 for a coffee?).

Comment: Clearly the problem would be a lot easier if you could make a few mapping trips with a human taking notes, or had some other way of assigning know locations to a few of the probes seen.

Comment: When you ask for an algorithm, it's best to characterize - as precisely as possible - what the input and desired output look like. You've left a lot of guesswork. Sounds like an interesting problem, so I hope you improve the question. Example: The input is 1) a map from device ids to of lists of station ids, the device routes 2) a map from route ids to lists of station ids, the actual routes 3) an integer triple [I,D,C] of max inserts, deletes and changes allowed for a device and actual route to match. The output is a map from device ids to sets of matching route ids.

Comment: This looks interesting. But as stated it's just too broad and informal! I also dislike the tag graph-database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify the problem (at the cost of losing information) by breaking your observations of all the probes seen in a journey up into overlapping observations of just two or three probes.

Then if somebody gives me a proposed allocation of probe points to positions in the network and a short section of two or three probes I can come up with the probability of seeing the final probe in the section given the first one or two probes and the allocation of probes to network positions. Looking at your graph, it is likely that you will see 6 if the previous two probes were 4 and 5, and unlikely that you will see 11 immediately after 4 and 5. You can treat the known station information as a special case of this - treat Station A as a probe with an initially known location that is always picked up.

Given a proposed allocation of probe points to positions you can then go through all of the short segments of probe and station information and sum up the logs of the probabilities that you get. This gives you a score to assess how credible that allocation of probe points to positions is. Now all you have to do is to find the allocation of probe points to positions that gives the highest score.

I would try hill-climbing from multiple random starts. Given a proposed assignment I would score alternative assignments by changing the position of one of the probe points and see if any of these alternative assignments got a higher score than the original. If so, modify the original and keep going until you have hill-climbed to a local optimum. You could also try a genetic algorithm, or you could try scoring and extending partial assignments of probe points to positions.

There might well be a HMM approach to this too. The hidden state would be the assignment of probes to positions in the network. Again, each short stretch of two or three probes seen could amount to an observation of behaviour from the HMM.

There is also a hidden markov model approach to assessing the probability of seeing an entire journey, given an allocation of probes to positions. The hidden state at each point is the location of the observer. You could assume that the observer moves to a random neighbour of the current position at each change of state (I'm not sure of the details - have you some means of knowing when you get to observe a new set of probes, or perhaps none at all, or do you just notice when the set of probes changes?). From this you can calculate the log probability of the sequence of probes seen during a journey. As before, sum the log probabilities to get the total log probability of all recorded journeys, given an allocation of probes to positions, and hill-climb on this from multiple random starts to find the allocation of probes to positions which gives you the highest log probability.